# Price Tables: what's the best position for "Best value" option on even grids?

Tags: layout, pricing, decision-making

Is there a documented *'best position'* for highlighting the *'best value'* or *'recommended'* option in a table with four columns? In tables with 3 or 5 columns, the best placement is typically the center. **But what about when there are 4 columns?** Should the *'best value'* be in the **second or third column**?

Please provide any supporting documents for this placement, as we have a tight deadline and no time for pre-testing (although we plan to test afterward).

Note: I know the [**Serial Position Effect**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial-position_effect) might play a role here, **making the 3rd column the right place**, but this is only a hunch, so I'd like to know if there's some kind of research o this since I couldn't find anything. Papers, articles or live examples are OK

Comment: If your second column is your best value, what would make your user consider the third column? Is it something like an "enterprise" level amount that they'll buy regardless of value?

Comment: hi @Izquierdo I mean where to place that "best value". Either way, and for reference, second and third columns are very different, so we can't make a direct comparison,  but we still want one of the choices to be selected over the other as much as possible.

Comment: Is the best value associated with the highest price in each column? Or are you considering adding "Best Value" to a mid-range price, based on other aspects?

Comment: it's a mid range

Comment: I am curious to know whether you reached a conclusion as to what the best position is for the best value option.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at a couple of pages where a range of different price table designs are displayed, and I think that you have to challenge some of the assumptions that are made relating to whether there is a definitive 'best' position for the design, or whether it is about making the design highlight a specific option you want to draw the user's attention to.

For example, this page lists [50 different pricing table examples](https://htmlburger.com/blog/pricing-table-examples/), or the one here with [11 pricing table designs](https://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2017/07/11-pricing-table-designs-that-really-sell/), I noticed that:

- There are indeed examples where the 2nd or 3rd option is highlighted, but there are also examples where they are not
- For pages with odd numbers of options, the middle options isn't always the one highlighted
- Some designs deliberately don't highlight a particular option, either to make the user go through them all, or to make it difficult to make comparisons

There is no question that in some of the designs, the serial position effect is at play, but I think it is easier to tailor the visual design to the information that you want to display rather than designing for a particular effect that the user is likely to be drawn to.

For example, I think if the options in a pricing table follow a linear progression that scales to some underlying business pricing model, then the user is looking for any cues that will suggest the level where the best value for money presents itself, regardless of where this falls in a row of even or odd numbered options. By default they might start looking from a specific position or remember certain options better, and this is where you can use visual design to highlight the option you want them to look at.

On the other hand, if the options in a pricing table is discreetly bundled into packages that are not easily compared, then this is where you could position things in places that they are likely to look at first and remember better.